# Ideal gas with sticky wall

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

A collection of $N$ point particles is held inside a cubic box of side $L$. The walls of the box are *sticky*. This means that when a particle collides with a wall, it stays attached for a short period of time $\tau$, and then it is released. When it is released, it goes out with the same velocity that it would have if the collision had been elastic in the first place.

**What is the spatial distribution of particles?** For simplicity, you can assume that only one of the walls is sticky, and the rest are normal. In this case there is only one gradient to be concerned with.

If there were no sticky wall, the distribution would be uniform. I have the intuition that the presence of the sticky wall will increase the concentration of particles near the wall. Think of ergodicity: since the particles spend more time near the wall ($\tau$ extra units), that means that the probability of finding particles near the wall should also be larger. But I am not sure how to prove this, nor how to find the quantitive distribution.

**Added: What is the velocity distribution of particles in the bulk of the box? And in the wall?**

Comment: Show effort and identify a specific aspect of the problem where you are stuck.

Comment: @DanielSank I added some comments. This is not a homework question.

Comment: The name of the "homework policy" is unfortunately very misleading. Whether or not a question is literally homework is completely irrelevant to the fact that questions like this one should show effort and ask something specific. See [this meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7162/should-we-rename-the-homework-policy).

Comment: @DanielSank I honestly do not see why the question is trivial.

Comment: Nobody said it was trivial.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [The Discrete Site Sticky Wall Model](http://www.dtic.mil/docs/citations/ADA168910) ([eprint](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a168910.pdf)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the set of particles with a velocity $v_i$ towards the "sticky" wall.

Then replace the sticky wall with a normal perfectly elastic wall, but locate it a distance ${(v_1 \times \tau)/}{2}$ behind the location of the sticky wall. **Note that the location of this wall is a function of the velocity under consideration**

This new, enlarged vessel will mimic exactly the behaviour of the sticky walled one, at least for particles with normal velocity $v_i$.

The sticky box has volume $L^3$;  the enhanced box has volume $L^2\times (L+{(v_1 \times \tau)/}{2})$

Can you see how the distribution of particles with different velocities will be affected by the sticky wall?

Edit:

All the particles will be uniformly distributed **spatially**.

However, the energy distribution will be skewed.

The presence of **free-flying** particles with a particular energy/velocity will be diminished.  A fraction of them can be visualized as being in the extra space;  the fraction in the real, $L^3$ space is just the ratio of that real volume to the volume including the moved wall.  **And that ratio changes for each different velocity.**

Consider:  a fast, high energy particle will spend $\tau$ stuck to the wall, perhaps $0.001 \tau$ on a round trip down the box and back, another $\tau$ stuck, and so on.  Almost never part of the free distribution.

But a slow particle might spend $\tau$ stuck in the wall; then spend $1000 \tau$ driftinnnng down the length and back, another $\tau$ stuck...  Almost always part of the free population.

Comment: I was thinking about this exact way of analyzing the problem. Then I realized that a slower particle would be "returned to the gas" relatively sooner than a faster particle (in a situation where the MFP is long compared to  $v\times \tau$, a cold particle would stay longer). Does this cause a cooling of the gas?

Comment: The box has effective volumes that are different for each particle, depending on the particle's velocity. I don't see how that's helfpful, sorry.

Comment: I think that @DJohnM has centered qualitatively the point: if you fix a population with one velocity you obtain that particles that lives in the extra volume are the one glue to the wall.
This is true for all velocity, so you have that in the true box the density is still uniform, and there are some particles stick on the wall.

Comment: @becko : if you want to find what is the fraction of particles stick on the wall you have to calculate the velocity distribution (that is unrelated to the glue on the wall in your formulation), and so it is the Maxwell distribution for an ideal gas, and integrate it multiplied for the fraction of particles stick on the wall with fixed velocity.

Comment: @AlessandroCandido I see. So that means that the distribution in the bulk of the box is still uniform. However, the density of particles stuck in the wall is a Dirac Delta, correct? In fact, using the extended box argument, the probability that a particle with velocity $v_i$ is stuck in the wall is $L^2 \times (v_i \tau)/2$

Comment: @AlessandroCandido Our comments were simultaneous. How do you know that the glue leaves the Maxwellian distribution unaffected? The faster particles have a higher probability of being stuck in the wall.

Comment: @becko I thought on it, I had the some doubt of you: the Maxwell distribution derives from the Boltzmann distribution of energy, and your setting with glue almost not affect energies.
To clarify: imagine the extended box, the only particles affected are ones in the extra space, so if time $\tau$ is sufficiently short the number is small and the distribution is negligible different (the characteristic time of the box is $L/\sqrt{k_B T/m}$.

Comment: @becko If the time $\tau$ is not short you have to impose Maxwell distribution for the fraction of particles _outside the wall_ $1- f$ ($f$ is the fraction of ones _in the wall_).
For each velocity you can find the fraction $f(v)$ so you can say that if the particles outside the wall with that velocity are $n(v)$ those in the wall are $n(v)f(v)/(1-f(v))$. You can calculate $f(v)$ as pointed out by DJohnM and $n(v)$ is the Maxwell distribution itself.
Integrating in $v$ you find $f$.

Comment: How can you be sure that the velocity distribution in the bulk of the box (particles outside the wall) is still Maxwellian? Although the wall returns the particles with the same energy, it has a tendency to retain more energetic particles. It seems to me that the Maxwellian distribution would have to be corrected, in the sense of decreasing the frequencies of fast particles (since those are in the wall). @AlessandroCandido

Comment: @becko You have to consider the derivation of Maxwell distribution. It comes out from Boltzmann distribution of energy, if Boltzmann holds so Mawell.
Boltzmann holds for a system in thermal equilibrium, and if the gas in the box is in thermal equilibrium only the part outside the wall is involved (the gas inside the wall has 0 energy and doesn't contribute to the temperature). This is the reason.

Comment: I am not convinced that the system is in thermal equilibrium.

Comment: This is an assumption, it means that you have a thermal bath in contact with it, that fix his temperature.

Comment: @becko  because the velocity are conserved by the walls and the glue if your system is insulated from the rest of the universe the velocity that you put in at the start time are the ones that you find at any time: they are conserved! So you can impose any velocity distribution you want and so you have to know it in order to exploit the calculus (if you fix the velocities for the particles outside the wall you have $n(v)$, if you fix all the velocities including the "virtual" ones of these particles in the wall you have $n(v)/(1-f(v))$)

Comment: @becko The important think is that if the system is thermal insulated you can't calculate the velocity distribution, because all velocity distributions are possible. Instead the hypothesis of thermal contact and fixed temperature fixes also there velocity distribution to the Maxwell one for the particles outside, as I previously discussed. Moreover there hypothesis that a macroscopic body "has a temperature" is reasonable and realistic :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is similar to phase equilibrium. Suppose you consider equilibrium between a liquid and its vapor. When a vapor molecule "hits" the liquid it does not rebound, but becomes part of the liquid and spends some time inside the liquid, before by pure chance it is ejected out again. Of course the time spent by a molecule inside the liquid is not fixed but a stochastic variable.

Larger stick-time $\tau$ is equivalent to the situation of low vapor pressure liquid. In other words, increasing $\tau$ will result in smaller fraction of molecules freely moving inside the box and the rest of them stuck to the walls when system reaches steady state. The molecule number concentration will be a step function, with change occurring at the sticky wall.

In your question the molecule is ejected from the sticky wall as if it were reflected (after time delay $\tau$). In the case of liquid-vapor system, molecule escaping the liquid has probably no memory of its velocity when it was last captured by the liquid. But if statistically the velocity distribution remains the same for molecules ejected from the sticky wall and for molecules that hit the sticky wall, the resulting velocity distribution inside the box (excluding walls) must be identical to that in the absence of sticky-walls.